# can i use RNN to measure the similarity between two variable length sequences?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

now i have two variable length sequences(like voice but not text),i want to exploit RNN to measure the similarity between them. Can RNN does that? I don't want to define the distance explicitly .Thanks for any suggestions:)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

There's a Python function to do this in a single line. If you want to use an RNN, go ahead, but this is a nice easy solution

```
import scipy.stats as sst    
D, pval = sst.kstest(seq1, seq2)
```